# Android Studio memory profiler have some serious memory issues

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, memory-leaks, profiler

I am trying to fix some memory leaks in my apps but I am always fighting with memory profiler instability itself instead of being able to focus on my task. Interestingly few people report this so here I am.
My project is huge but I already increased recommended Android Studio memory values.
I just want to capture Heap Dump, because recording is totally unstable obviously and even more system memory is necessary, but even with just heap dump capture when I am jumping between various captures my android studio gets to the point I have to kill it start again what really slows me down. Its really killing my productivity, to find memory leaks is hard task but without working tool its super hard. I have MacBook Air M1 8 GB ram that is really snappy but now I believe I seriously need better machine with more memory or something is seriously wrong here.

I am running Android Studio Bumble Bee 2021.1.1 Patch 2

I am getting mostly this:

[image]

Until in hangs totally.

My memory settings are like this now:

2048 Max Heap Size, Gradle 2048, Kotlin 1024.

The problem is I even cannot increase Max Heap Size in Settings so probably I have to alter some configuration directly.

My question is what memory increase is really necessary so I can do simple heap dump without getting unresponsive android Studio how to change it or whatever tip to be able to capture heap dump of my app running in emulator while being able to browse it with search to look for instances, maybe som other tool ?.
My desire is also to not allocate unnecessary ram so I can still run multiple apps and emulators at once if necessary.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you say you're jumping between captures, do you mean you have more than one open at once? Because those things are very memory intensive, and an 8GB machine will struggle (this kind of thing is why 16 or even 32GB is recommended for developers a lot of the time - you can really eat up memory with tools, virtual devices etc). If you only have one open at a time, but it starts to eat up memory if you do multiple dumps in a session - I used to have that issue too (with 16GB) but they improved the memory handling. But if you have to restart, you have to restart unfortunately

Comment: One thing you could try is running your app on a virtual device with less of a memory footprint - it's not just the dump itself, it's the memory being used to emulate the device too. Pare it down to just the emulator you need, and try not to have too many dumps open - preferably just the one you're looking at. If you're looking for memory leaks, the signs should be in the dump itself, not in comparison to another one (e.g. too many instances of a particular object when you know how many there *should* be). And maybe use a standalone hprof viewing tool outside of AS, if you have to

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when setting debuggable false temporarily for your build you want to profile you get less memory issues.

```
...
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }...
```

Also there is some trick like

```
<profileable
    android:shell="true"
    tools:targetApi="q" />
```

That is documented here https://developer.android.com/studio/profile. My first solution was to use this `profileable` together with changing `debuggable` to `false` for `debug` `buildType` in `build.gradle`. Then I found out that I just have to use not debuggable build for profile to have less memory footprint and then... when I updated Android Studio, as is usual for us developers, problems with IDE magically disappeared, for now.